# jQuery css height increases but does not decrease, Foundation, Flex

Tags: jquery, flexbox, zurb-foundation

Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBNyXP?editors=1111

If you change the height of the viewport the height will go up but it never goes down. I would think that since it can increase that it should be able to decrease as well but it does not.

Best viewed in "Full page" mode:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var parentHeight = $('#parent').outerHeight();
    console.log('height', parentHeight);
    $('#grandchild').css('height', parentHeight);
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#parent #child {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div id="grandchild">Grandchild</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of "#grandchild" has a hardcoded height, remove the hardcoded height and it will adjust itself according to the available height.

Comment: Hard coded =/= can change? I thought the jQuery value would change as the height changed. Isn't there supposed to be a way to do this in jQuery?

Comment: jQuery's .height() will always return the content height and in the content, there is "#grandchild" with hardcoded height. so I do not think that there is a way to do this in jQuery.